# MySQL unable to detect line breaks from jq generated CSV

Tags: mysql, bash, jq

I have written a small Bash script to read a JSON file to CSV for import into MySQL. The below example is a boiled down version of what we have - the JSON is quite complex making it difficult to import directly into MySQL.

A CSV will allow us to import to a temporary table and use the data in a number of different ways with validation etc.

Our issue is, the line breaks in the generated CSV file are not recognized by MySQL using `'\n'`. I have tried `'\r\n'` and validated with `file -k` the filetype `(ASCII text, with very long lines)`. I can successfully count the number of `'\n'` in the command line, so I'm confident the text file is correctly generated.

Regardless, MySQL fails to recognize the line break for row termination with `ERROR 1262 (01000) at line 5: Row 1 was truncated; it contained more data than there were input columns`.

**Editing the file down to a single row imports successfully**, so I know the fields in the CSV match up to the table.

Here is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
{

# Define variables
source "$_source/../_config.sh"

_today=$(date '+%Y-%m-%d');
_source="$(dirname "$0")"

jq -r '.data | [.val1, .val2, .val3] | @csv' <$_source/raw/"$_today".json >raw/"$_today".csv

read -d '' SQL1 << EOM
    set unique_checks = 0;
    set foreign_key_checks = 0;
    set sql_log_bin=0;

    LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'raw/"$_today".csv' 
    REPLACE INTO TABLE imports 
    CHARACTER SET utf8 

    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
    OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'

    (@col1, @col2, @col3)
    SET 
        val1 = TRIM(@col1),
        val2 = TRIM(@col2),
        val3 = TRIM(@col3)
    ;
EOM

_result=$(echo "$SQL1" | mysql $_db -u$_user -p$_pass -s -N)

}
```

With `jq`, I have tried the `-a` and the `-c` flag as well with no noticeable difference. Any ideas why MySQL doesn't see the newlines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem arises because of the way you're reading in the SQL commands.

To illustrate, consider:

```
#!/bin/bash
read -d '' SQL1 << EOM
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
EOM

echo "$SQL1"
```

This produces:

```
LINES TERMINATED BY 'n'
```

So if you're going to use the HEREDOC technique to specify the LINES TERMINATED BY value, you'll either need to write

```
LINES TERMINATED BY '\\\n'
```

or use the -r option of `read`.

Since `\n` is supposedly the default anyway (at least in MYSQL V8), you could try simply omitting the LINES TERMINATED BY specification.

Comment: @DeweyOx, no, you need the `read -r` flag to not mess with backlash unescaping.